# Perl: Converting strings to Unicode

Tags: string, perl, text, unicode, translate

I have a MySql database that stores strings with the Unicode characters encoded using an XML type format (i.e., &#nnnnn; ).  An example of one of these strings would be: &#27010;&#36848; which represents the Unicode characters: 概述

Perl lets me make this conversion in my application if I hard-code the strings in the format:

```
\x{6982}\x{8ff0}
```

or even:

```
\N{U+6982}\N{U+8ff0}
```

To me it seems like a simple matter of changing the format from &#nnnnn; to \x{nnnn}
The Perl application seems to require hex numbers whereas the MySql is outputting integers.

I wanted to do this simple conversion in Regex.  So I matched the integer using:

```
m/\&\#(\d{3,5});/;
```

Then I converted the match to hex using:
sprintf('{%04x}',$1)
Then I added in the necessary: \x{ }
I was easily able to create strings that contained: "\x{6982}\x{8ff0}"
But none of them were printed by the application as Unicode.  They were simply printed as they were created: symbols and text.

I found out that if you hard-coded these strings into the program, Perl would "interpolate" them into Unicode characters.  But if they were created as a string, the "interpolation" did not take place.

I tried to force the interpolation by using various functions such as:
Encode::decode('UTF-8', "some string" ); 
Encode::encode('UTF-8', "some string" ); 
But that wasn't what those functions were intended for.
I also tried to use Perl's manual string interpolation

```
$v="${ \($v) }";
```

But that did not convert the string "\x{6982}\x{8ff0}" into Unicode.  It simply remained the same string as before.

I came across an example using "eval()".

```
while($unicodeString =~ m/\&\#(\d{3,5});/) {
    $_=$unicodeString;     ## in the XML form of (spaces added so you could see it here): & #27010; & #36848;
    m/\&\#(\d{3,5});/;     ## Matches the integer number in the Unicode
    my $y=q(\x).sprintf('{%04x}',$1); ## Converts the integer to hex and adds the \x{}
    my $v = eval qq{"$y"}; ## Performs the interpolation of the string to get the Unicode
    $unicodeString =~ s/\&\#(\d{3,5});/$v/;  ## Replaces the old code with the new Unicode character
}
```

This conversion works now.  But I am not happy with the repeated use of eval() to convert each character: one-at-a-time.  I could build my string in the While loop and then simply eval() the new string.  But I would prefer to only eval() those small strings that were specifically matched in Regex.

Is there a better way of converting an XML string (with Unicode characters shown as integers) into a string that contains the actual Unicode characters?

How can I easily go from a string that contains: 
&#25105;&#35748;&#35782;&#21040;&#33258;&#24049;&#30340;&#38271;&#22788;&#21644;&#30701;&#22788;&#65292;&#24182;&#36861;&#27714;&#33258;&#25105;&#21457;&#23637;&#12290;

to one with:
我认识到自己的长处和短处，并追求自我发展。

The documents I need to convert contain thousands of these characters.

Comment: Have you already tested the cpan module [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities)? Maybe it can meet your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example of how you can replace the unicode escapes using the [`chr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr) function:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw( :encoding(utf-8) :std );

my $str = "&#27010;&#36848;";
$str =~ s/&#(\d+);/chr $1/eg;
printf "%vX\n", $str;
say $str;
```

**Output**:

```
6982.8FF0
概述
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I have tried using this suggested regex substitution and it works.  The chr $1 was the key I was looking for.  This really helped me to eliminate the multiple calls to eval().  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a module that decode XML entities because they are normally only found in XML, and the XML parser handles them. But, it's pretty easy to recreate.

```perl
use feature qw( say state );

sub decode_xml_entities_inplace {
   state $ents = {
      amp  => "&",
      lt   => "<",
      gt   => ">",
      quot => '"',
      apos => "'",
   };
   
   $_[0] =~ s{
      &
      (?: \# (?: x([0-9a-fA-F]+)
             |   ([0-9]+)
             )
      |   (\w+)
      )
      ;
   }{
      if    (defined($1)) { chr(hex($1))      }
      elsif (defined($2)) { chr($2)           }
      else                { $ents->{$3} // $& }
   }xeg;
}

my $s = "&#27010;&#36848;";
decode_xml_entities_inplace($s);
say $s;
```

Of course, if you simply need to handle the decimal numeric entities, the above simplifies to

```perl
use feature qw( state );

my $s = "&#27010;&#36848;";
$s =~ s{ &\# ([0-9]+) ; }{ chr($1) }xeg;
say $s;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I have tried implementing the above code. The use of "state" and "s{}{}" was a new lesson for me.  I also learned a little about non-capturing groups using the "(?: )" syntax.  Your solution didn't exactly do what I needed.  Your solution create new strings like the following:  &#是&#一&#种&#诊&#断&#工&#具&#，&#可&#为&#您.  As you can see, the unicode characters are inserted by the chr() function that you refer to in the substitution.  However, the "&#" are also being inserted with the unicode because of the non-capturing groups in the matching part of your regex.

Comment: You also suggested an alternate (shorter) version of the replacement using: s{ &# ([0-9]+) ; }{ chr($1) }xeg;   I tried implementing this solution as well.  It didn't work out, but not because of any syntax error.  The problem, I think, was the extra spaces before and after the characters to be captured.  I reduced the spacing in the regex to: s{&#([0-9]+);}{chr $1}eg; and this worked just fine.  Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: Forgot to escape `#` and there was a missing `)`. Fixed.